# How to use curly brackets with grep

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to grep `mouli`,`mouli1`,`mouli2` etc from one of my file. I have used all the below:

```
grep \\{mouli\\} example.txt  

grep m\\} example.txt

grep m\\> example.txt

grep \\<mouli\\> example.txt
```

And I'm not getting anything. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? And how does this \{n,m\} work?

Comment: and why not `grep 'mouli[[:digit:]]' file` ? oh, an `i`, hmm.. `grep 'moul. ' file` (Is there a spaces after `moul?` ? Good luck.

Comment: hey shelter, i know that alternative to grep it. i just wanna know how exactly  \{n,m\} working? and trying to get the output through this command. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Most of your examples only show a closing brace. You want something like `'moul.\{1,3\}'` which apply only to the `.` char, so you can match the equivalent of `moul?`, `moul??`, `moul???` . .... ALSO, reduce number of backslashes required by using single quotes around your target str. i.e. `'moul.\{1,3\}'` . Good luck.

Comment: your example commands show ``\\``... are the double back slashes because you added another for formatting?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with multiple digits following "mouli":

```
grep "mouli[0-9]*" example.txt
```

If you only want 0 or 1 digits following "mouli":

```
grep "\<mouli[0-9]\{,1\}\>" example.txt
```